# Bash - retrieve the last modified file with some extension

Tags: bash, file, search

How can I get the last modified file with some extension in bash and than do something on it?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, if the extension is **.jpg**:

```
last_modified_file="$(find . -type f -name \*.jpg -printf "%T@ %p\0" | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0";} {if (NR==1){minmtime=$1; $1=""; lastmodified=$0;} else if (minmtime<$1){minmtime=$1; $1=""; lastmodified=$0;}} END{print substr(lastmodified,4)}')"

# do something
printf "The last modified file is named %s\n" "${last_modified_file}"
```

The **find** lists all files in current directory and sub directories with a filename ending with **.jpg**, and **awk** prints only the last modified one.

The name of the file found is stored in the variable **last_modified_file**.